# How to edit the length of a color box?

Tags: color, align, boxes

I've typed my Resume and Im using a color box, with a line underneath it. However the grey colored box doesn't reach the full length of the page width.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=0.9in, right=0.8in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedright
\def\bull{\vrule height 0.8ex width .7ex depth -.1ex }    

\newcommand{\lineunder}{\vspace*{-8pt} \\ \hspace*{-18pt} \hrulefill \\} %command for the Line to be drawn

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{.90}
\newcommand{\headergrey}[1]{\hspace*{-18pt} \colorbox{mygrey} 
    {\begin{minipage}
    {\textwidth}{\textsc{#1}}
    \end{minipage}}\lineunder}

\begin{document}

\headergrey{Objective}
    Seeking a Full Time position in the area of Blah blah blah Blah 
\end{document}
```

See the image attached so as to what i mean please. [image]

Comment: In general I recommend my `adjustbox` package to easily create and modify such boxes. However, it is not yet possible to draw a line only on one side of the box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not ignore LaTeX warnings about overfull boxes. The basic problem in your original is that the box constructed does not fit on the page. The inner minipage is `\textwidth` wide but `\colorbox`, like `\fbox` adds padding around the box of length `\fboxsep` so the box was `2\fboxsep` (6pt) too wide and then it was at the start of a paragraph so further indented by the paragraph indent, sticking it into the left margin.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=0.9in, right=0.8in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedright
\def\bull{\vrule height 0.8ex width .7ex depth -.1ex }    


\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{.90}
\newcommand{\headergrey}[1]{\par\noindent{\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\hspace*{-18pt}\colorbox{mygrey} 
    {\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep+18pt\relax}
\vspace{2pt}%
\textsc{\strut\hspace{3pt}#1}\par
\hrule
    \end{minipage}}\par\smallskip}}

\begin{document}

\headergrey{Objective}
    Seeking a Full Time position in the area of Blah blah blah Blah 
\end{document}
```

Comment: David, The grey box now covers that gap, however there is a huge separation after the text like this (http://imgur.com/0Ax0Tv8). I tried to play around with the  \par before \hrulefill and replace it with a \\ and few other things, however no change!

Comment: @Karan sorry I'd copied `\hrulefill` from the question but used it as if it was `\hrule` so you got an extra paragraph, updated with image.

Comment: it works, however, as you see, the Header line in my original starts a little indented, so how to shift it towards the left (just like the original)?

Comment: @Karan updated with header outdented into margin

Answer (score 5):

Among other possible methods, you can set the box in a `tabular` instead. It gives you better control over the entire heading construct:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=0.9in, right=0.8in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{colortbl}% http://ctan.org/pkg/colortbl

\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{.90}
\newcommand{\headergrey}[1]{%
  \noindent\hspace*{-15pt}%
  \tabular{p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep+15pt}}\cellcolor{mygrey}\textsc{#1}\\\hline\endtabular%
  \par\nobreak}%

\pagestyle{empty}\raggedright
\begin{document}

\headergrey{Objective}
    Seeking a Full Time position in the area of Blah blah blah Blah 

\end{document}
```

The horizontal negative indent (hang) is `15pt`. Also, if required, you can increase the vertical gap between the heading and subsequent text.

Comment: It gives me an error:
! Undefined control sequence.
\headergrey ...dth -2\tabcolsep +15pt}}\cellcolor 
                                                  {mygrey}\textsc {#1}\\\hli...
l.26 \headergrey{Objective}

Comment: @Karan: I can't diagnose the problem with only this. You should [post your full code at PasteBin](http://pastebin.com), or include it in an [edit to your post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/115489/edit).

Comment: Hi Werner, Thank you for that advice. Here you go, its on Pastebin (http://pastebin.com/M8LkbWwN#)

Also, I stuck with 
    \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
instead of your suggestion
    \usepackage{colortbl}

But i dont think that should create a big problem right?

Comment: Werner, I also tried this where i wrote \begin{tabular} and \end{tabular}  - still gives an error. 
(http://pastebin.com/gMB2FZSs)

Comment: @Karan: [`colortbl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/colortbl) provides `\cellcolor`, so you need it in order for my solution to work. Note that `colortbl` loads [`color`](http://ctan.org/pkg/color) so you only have to load `colortbl` with the same options you would normally load `color` with.

Comment: great. I installed it and it works. 
now how do i shift the the 'Objective' little more on the left, just like my original where there is not much gap in the beginning?

Comment: Also, i notced one problem, the horizontal line now does not extend all the way (since you didnt use hrulefill), and if we use hrulefill, the format screws up. Take a look at this: 
(http://pastebin.com/Xd1jWqBb)
 and (http://imgur.com/92Z9qX3). Also from previous comment how to reduce the gap where the grey box starts and the text in between it?

Comment: @Karan: In your code for `\headergrey` you use `-3\tabcolsep` which should be `-2\tabcolsep`, since there is only 2 places where LaTeX inserts a gap/space within a single column (on the left and right). To shift the text in the grey box further to the left, insert something like `\hspace*{-5pt}` before `\textsc{#1}` in the definition as well.