# How to extend the horizontal line and colored box all the way?

Tags: tables, spacing, horizontal-alignment, color

1. I want to extend the horizontal line and the colored box all the way to the end of the page, however using `\hrulefill` (instead of `\hline`, screws up the format.)

   This is my code: http://pastebin.com/Xd1jWqBb
   and this is what it looks like:

[image]

2. Also, how do i reduce the gap between the colorbox and the start of the text within it?
3. If I were to use Answer 2 (located in my code) i get this:

[image]

however the heading should be shifted towards the left. If I do that, how do i extend the color and the line all the way to the end.

So ultimately i want

[image]

but with the colorbox extended as well.

I posted a similar question and the above problems are the by products of the answers given from the other post. (Ref: [How to edit the length of a color box?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115489/how-to-edit-the-length-of-a-color-box))

Comment: Please edit your question to add [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) on this site. A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Maybe you could use and `\indent` at the beginning of "Seeking a Full Time..." instead?

Comment: This appears to be the identical question to your previous one?

Comment: @David: No it wasnt identical, but as i said similar. this was a problem which was a byproduct of that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For such a color box problem I would recommend a color box package like `mdframed` or `tcolorbox`.

A `tcolorbox` solution would be:

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox}%  preamble AFTER \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color} 

...

\newcommand{\headergrey}[1]{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[enlarge left by=-15pt,width=\linewidth+15pt,
    arc=0pt,toprule=0pt,bottomrule=0.4pt,leftrule=0pt,rightrule=0pt,
    boxsep=0pt,left=6pt,right=6pt,bottom=4pt,top=4pt,
    colback=black!10!white,fontupper=\scshape,
    after=\par\nobreak]#1\end{tcolorbox}}%

\headergrey{Objective}
Seeking a Full Time position in the area of balh blah blah blah.
\vspace*{6pt}

\headergrey{Education}
\school {University of Latex}{Latex U.S.A.}{May 2013}{Masters of Science in Latex}{Adviser: }{GPA: xxxx}
```

This gives the following result (with your output in comparison):

[image]

You can shift `OBJECTIVE` by adjusting the `left=6pt` option value.